# Python3 reversing an inputed sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that reverses a sentence that a user inputs but when I run the program I am not getting the sentence in reverse. Bellow is my code

```
sentence=input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sentence_reverse(sentence):
    words=sentence.split()
    newsentence=words.reverse()
    return (newsentence)

print(sentence_reverse(sentence))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sentence_reverse(s):
    return ' '.join(s.split()[::-1])

print(sentence_reverse(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

or :

```
def reverse2(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

Comment: They seem to want to reverse by word, not by letter.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` is an in-place operation, meaning it reverses `words` itself and doesnt return anything. So instead of returning `newsentence`, you want to return `words` like so:

```
sentence=input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sentence_reverse(sentence):    
    words=sentence.split()
    words.reverse()
    return words

print(sentence_reverse(sentence))

>>>Enter a sentence: hello world
>>>['world', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The reason is because you are using `split()` but it does not convert your input string into the list of its character. It just make a list with one element, which is your input string. Instead, convert the string to list using `list()` function, and then convert it back to string using `join()` function. In addition to that, `reverse()` returns nothing. So, you have to returns the `words` variable instead.

```
sentence=input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sentence_reverse(sentence):
    words=list(sentence)
    words.reverse()
    return ''.join(words)

print(sentence_reverse(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplest way to solve your problem:

```
sentence=input('Enter a sentence: ')

def sentence_reverse(sentence):
    words= sentence.split() # breaks the sentence into words
    rev_sentence= ''
    for word in words:
        rev_sentence = ' ' + word + rev_sentence
    return rev_sentence

print(sentence_reverse(sentence))
```

Input: `Hi please reverse me`

Ouput: `me reverse please Hi`

Hope this helps you. Kindly let me know if anything else is needed.